# Pseudo registers in MSVC

Tags: c, visual-c++

Borland C has pseudo-Registers _AX,_BX, _FLAGS etc that could be used in 'C' code to save the registers to temp variables.

Is there any MSVC equivalent?  I tried @AX, @BX, etc, but the compiler (MSVC1.5) gave error ('40' unrecognized symbol).

I'm developing a 16-bit pre-boot app and can't use .
Thanks.

Comment: In case you're not aware... 1.x versions of MSC are very quirky when inline assembly is used.  If you see weird bugs, look at the assembly output of the compiler.  Certain things in inline assembly will disable the optimizer for the code following in the entire C/CPP file.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to have pseudo registers if you only move values between registers and variables. example:

```
int a = 4;
int b = 999;
__asm
{
    mov eax, a; // eax equals to 4
    mov b, eax; // b equals to eax
}
// b equals to 4 now
```

edit: to copy the flags into a variable and back to flags again, you can use `LAHF` and `SAHF` instructions. example:

```
int flags = 0;
__asm
{
  lahf;
  mov flags, eax;
}
 flags |= (1 << 3);
__asm
{
  mov eax, flags;
  sahf;
  // 4th bit of the flag is set
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  What would be the MSVC equivalent of _FLAGS ?