# psuedo global variable in c

Tags: c, visual-studio, global-variables

An interview question asked very frequently. But, i'm not clear with the explanation, which i found on different websites. Because, when i'm trying to execute this code, then it shows `_AX` undeclared error.

```
main()
  {
   int i;
   i = abc();
   printf("%d",i);
  }
  abc()
  {
   _AX = 1000;
  }
```

people says `_AX` is the **pseudo global variable**, that's why it shows output **1000**.

**Note : - It showing error `_AX` undeclared, but when i declared the variable, then it shows some garbage value  **

Comment: Note that any identifiers beginning with either an underscore followed by a capital letter or two underscores is considered to be reserved by the compiler/implementation.  Since `_AX` matches that pattern, you know right away that it's some compiler-specific feature.

Comment: I think it is part of some dos extension of C. Don't think it is part of C standard. Which compiler are you using ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This comes up frequently? It's utter nonsense. Presumably `_AX` is some compiler-specific notation to access the "ax" register, which is used on x86 for return values. However there's no reason to believe the value in the register should not get clobbered between the assignment and function return. This program is invoking undefined behavior. If somebody offering you a job expects you to know such invalid practices, RUN. FAST. They're not competent.

Comment: `_AX` is a Borland C extension, so unless you are using a Borland compiler it won't be defined.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891566/pseudo-registers-in-msvc

Comment: More red flags: they're using old bad practices like implicit function declarations and implicit `int`.

Comment: Note that this sort of extension -- direct access to registers and guarantees by the compiler that the registers hold their values between C statements -- basically precludes the compiler doing **any** optimization. The compiler is treating C as a minimally-structured wrapper for assembly language, meaning the code is generates will be atrociously bad.